# Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

before you send me thousand of links to the problem of other please read my code. i googled my problem for about an hour and tried every suggestion i could find. I got a similar code example from php book but its not working on my local server. 
my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "poi_site");
if ($mysqli->connect_error){
    echo "something went wrong!".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
echo "db connection is stable";
$mysqli->close();


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM cities;");
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {                                  
echo " {$row['name']}";
}
$result->close();
```

i already tried to get a error output and that showed me that "result" is null, like i expexted the problem from the other people. 
my errors at the moment are:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in ...
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in ...

dont know how to solve the problem. thanks

EDIT: sorry i had a typo in the code here, it was right on my code!

Comment: Closing your connection before making a query is sure to be a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrong ";" after cities in here:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM cities;");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM cities");
```

This has to be $result instead of $ergebnis

```
while($row = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {           
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

U don't need "{" and "}" after and before the $row statement here:

```
echo " $row['name']";
echo " $row['name']";
```

Your closing the database, before the query here:

```
echo "db connection is stable";
$mysqli->close();
```

Delete this line!

Comment: sorry i had a typo in the code here, it was right on my code!

Comment: If all those 3 things don't work, you dont get a result from database, maybe its your connection, OR the table is empty

Comment: Delete the $mysqli->close() line above.

Comment: Its not needed tho, useless, but yeah, u can use it if u want to

Comment: Just dleete the $mysqli->close() line! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {
```

to

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
```

check the very first example here

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

UPDATE :

```
$mysqli->close();
```

is done prior to fetch so this should be the last line of your code after u have done with all the operations are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM cities;");
while($row = $ergebnis->fetch_array()) {                                    
echo " {$row['name']}";
}
```

with this one and check if also you haven't result

```
$result = $mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT name FROM cities");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                                    
echo " {$row['name']}";
}
```